# Create project in Jira using Rest API

Tags: python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

```
"ket": "DEMOCREATE",
    "name":"DEMO ",
    "projectTypeKey":"business",
    "projectTemplateKey":"com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-simplified-procurement",
    "description":"Rest Demo Project",
    "leadAccountId":"",
    "url":"",
    "assigneeType":"PROJECT_LEAD",
    "avatarId":1250
}
```

Tried to create a project using python rest-api and tested in the postman got 404 error, wants tp know what are the exact thing that have to fill in the **"leadAccountId":"",**
**"url":"",**, **your text**  and want to know what are fields mandatory while creating project or issue for json objects?

Comment: Are you using the JIRA Rest API then using Python to call those APIs, OR are using a certain Python package _specifically_ for JIRA? If you are using a Python package, which one exactly? Because you tagged your question with both [tag:jira-rest-api] and [tag:python-jira], which would result in 2 different implementations. Have you checked either of the linked documentation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.